# Typescript, interface, type, multiple optional properties, property conditioned on other property

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have need of an interface or type that requires the property `updatedAt` if the property `updatedBy` is present (and vis a versa); however, it should allow for neither property to be set.

```js
interface BaseRow {
    id: string
    createdAt: string
    createdBy: string
}

interface Updated {
    updatedAt: string
    updatedBy: string
}

interface UpdatedRow extends BaseRow, Updated {}

type Row = BaseRow | UpdatedRow
```

Based on the above, I would expect that the following would cause the typescript compiler to throw an error because `updatedAt` is present but `updatedBy` is not.

```js
const x: Row = {
    id: 'someID',
    createdAt: 'someISO',
    createdBy: 'someID',
    updatedAt: 'someISO'
}
```

The above does not however throw any error.

Why doesn't the above solution work as expected? What is the best way to achieve an `interface` or `type` that conditionally requires two or more properties?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20BaseRow%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20createdAt%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20createdBy%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Updated%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20updatedAt%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20updatedBy%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20UpdatedRow%20extends%20BaseRow%2C%20Updated%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Row%20%3D%20BaseRow%20%7C%20UpdatedRow%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20Row%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20'someID'%2C%0D%0A%20%20createdAt%3A%20'someISO'%2C%0D%0A%20%20createdBy%3A%20'someID'%2C%0D%0A%20%20updatedAt%3A%20'someISO'%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Seems to me like TS might just think `x` is just a `Row` type with an extra `updatedAt` property instead of a `UpdatedRow` type..

Comment: @aznbanana9 That does not make sense because the compiler still throws an error if you add an unknown property, but doesn't throw an error for `updatedAt` or `updatedBy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the PR that implements strict checking on object [literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823) the check that is performed is :

> ... it is an error for the object literal to specify properties that don't exist in the target type

While the properties are on different branches of the union type, the property exists on the union type. Since the other updated property does not exist, the object literal, does not conform to the `UpdatedRow` interface, but it does conform to the `Row` interface, so it is assignable to the variable. This is why there is not error.

A solution, which may or may not be applicable in your case, is to ensure that an updated row is incompatible with a non updated row by adding a string property that is typed to a different string literal type on the two interfaces:

```
interface BaseRow {
    id: string
    createdAt: string
    createdBy: string
}

interface Updated {
    type: 'u'
    updatedAt: string
    updatedBy: string
}

interface UpdatedRow extends BaseRow, Updated {}

type Row = (BaseRow & { type: 'n'})  | UpdatedRow

const x: Row = { // Error, no updatedBy
    type: 'u',
    id: 'someID',
    createdAt: 'someISO',
    createdBy: 'someID',
    updatedAt: 'someISO'
}

const x2: Row = { // Error, with updatedAt is not assignable to (BaseRow & { type: 'n'}) 
    type: 'n',
    id: 'someID',
    createdAt: 'someISO',
    createdBy: 'someID',
    updatedAt: 'someISO'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought I was asking an easy question and that there was some straightforward way to achieve. It seems like there should be a better way and I am surprised that tsc doesn't support this fairly common scenario. It may even be preferable to change the structure of the runtime data where possible to combine `updatedBy` and `updatedAt` to the same property `updated?: { by: string, at: string }` . I'm going to give it another 48 hours and if nobody has a better idea, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @RichardForrester 10x, yes this seems like a common scenario, but I think this was a deliberate decision by the ts team, I checked the code and the handling for this scenario specifically tests that the property be in any of the types in the union, which I agree is not ideal

Comment: @RichardForrester I found a work around for dealing with this issue, you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827802/how-to-limit-properties-in-typescript-objects-to-strictly-defined-properties/48828057#48828057